# Fold name without date for emacs package installation

Tags: emacs

I noticed that when I install a package for emacs, it is usually installed in a fold with a dated name, as an indicator for its version
e.g.
~/emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-20130218.2229...

that is super ugly, when i try to update it, what emacs does is: uninstall the one with older date and install the one with newer date.it also cause very much inconvenience for configurations. e.g., i have to setup the path for my snippet as:

`(setq yas/snippet-dirs "~/emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-20130218.2229/snippets")`

that means everytime i upgrade my yasnippet, i have to change my configuration....
is there a way to install package without dated fold name? and the version information is saved in smarter way?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can avoid the versioning on the folder names. That seems to be used by `package.el` for dependencies.

For your setup, you could work around it with something like

```
(setq yas/snippet-dirs
      (concat (file-name-as-directory
               (car (directory-files package-user-dir t "yasnippet")))
              "snippets"))
```

Comment: i agree that your method may resolve this issue, thanks! but i still want to say that this is not a nice way for emacs to manage its package. 30 years old software is still naive ...